# WiFi suddenly can't connect

Tags: wireless, networking

I am unable to connect to my wifi. It works with the cable plugged in. Nothing happened before this problem suddenly occurred. I can see the networks that are available.
I can connect to my network with other devices. I tried it with an ubuntu external drive and a fedora boot-stick but it wouldn't connect in either environment as well.
Computer model: Asus x501A
Ubuntu version: 14.04

Comment: Did your notebook EVER have a wifi connection set up?

Comment: Yes WiFi has been working fine for ages. (Also it is a laptop not a notebook if that makes a difference)

Comment: What is the device `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

Comment: Ran the device check, results:
`Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter 168c:0032 (rev 01)
Subsystem: AzureWave Device 1a3b:1186
Kernel driver: ath9k

Ethernet controller 0200: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] rev 0a
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer INc. Device [1043:14f7]
Kernel driver: r8169 `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a router problem

- could tell because i could connect to other wifi signals
- connected to my router with a wired connection and reset everything (except for full factory reset) in the diagnostics menu
- router is a 2wire (router IP: 172.16.1.254)
- i found the router settings via the browser http://

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of

```
rfkill list
```

If it shows a "hard block", then run:

```
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf
```

and reboot. Check the buttons (if any)

Comment: Checked the output of rfkill list
Says no on both hard blocked and soft blocked
Any other suggestions? (Wifi still not working!)
Thank you